# cocoapods dylib dependency use_frameworks

Tags: sqlite, cocoapods, icu

I have built a dynamic library (to add ICU support in this case) which i need to add as a dependency to a pod. For that I created a pod with the following podspec (I removed things like authors, license, ... to keep it short)

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name     = 'unicode'
  s.version  = '57.0'
  s.source              = { :git => "git@bitbucket.org:mycompany/unicode.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }
  s.requires_arc = false
  s.platform = :ios, '8.0'

  s.default_subspecs = 'all'

  s.subspec 'all' do |ss|
    ss.header_mappings_dir = 'icu4c/include'
    ss.source_files = 'icu4c/include/**/*.h'
    ss.public_header_files = 'icu4c/include/**/*.h'
    ss.vendored_libraries = 'Frameworks/lib*.dylib'
  end

end
```

Here i have a second pod where i need to link these libraries too

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name     = 'sqlite3'
  s.version  = '3.14.2'
  s.summary  = 'SQLite is an embedded SQL database engine'
  s.documentation_url = 'https://sqlite.org/docs.html'
  s.homepage = 'https://github.com/clemensg/sqlite3pod'
  s.authors  = { 'Clemens Gruber' => 'clemensgru@gmail.com' }

  v = s.version.to_s.split('.')
  archive_name = "sqlite-amalgamation-"+v[0]+v[1].rjust(2, '0')+v[2].rjust(2, '0')+"00"
  #s.source   = { :http => "https://www.sqlite.org/#{Time.now.year}/#{archive_name}.zip" }
  s.source              = { :git => "git@bitbucket.org:wrthphoenixspeedy/sqlite3.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }
  s.requires_arc = false
  s.platform = :ios, '8.0'

  s.default_subspecs = 'common'

  s.subspec 'common' do |ss|
    ss.source_files = "#{archive_name}/sqlite*.{h,c}"
    ss.osx.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'OTHER_CFLAGS' => '$(inherited) -DHAVE_USLEEP=1' }
    # Disable OS X / AFP locking code on mobile platforms (iOS, tvOS, watchOS)
    sqlite_xcconfig_ios = { 'OTHER_CFLAGS' => '$(inherited) -DHAVE_USLEEP=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOCKING_STYLE=0' }
    ss.ios.pod_target_xcconfig = sqlite_xcconfig_ios
    ss.tvos.pod_target_xcconfig = sqlite_xcconfig_ios
    ss.watchos.pod_target_xcconfig = sqlite_xcconfig_ios
  end

  # enable support for icu - International Components for Unicode
  s.subspec 'icu' do |ss|
    ss.dependency 'sqlite3/common'
    ss.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'OTHER_CFLAGS' => '$(inherited) -DSQLITE_ENABLE_ICU=1' }
    ss.dependency           'unicode', '57.0'
    ss.libraries = 'icucore', 'icudata.57.1', 'icui18n.57.1', 'icuio.57.1', 'icule.57.1', 'iculx.57.1', 'icutu.57.1', 'icuuc.57.1'
  end

end
```

And with these i am able to compile it. Cocoapods is copying these libraries on build time into the folder *../Frameworks/* rather than to do while on run time. Instead it fails because it says that it doesn't find the library in *../lib*.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: ../lib/libicudata.57.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/9663CB3A-6ACD-487E-A92D-48F8AFE5260C/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Reason: image not found
```

I have to use *use_frameworks!* because i am using some Swift frameworks too.

So i am doing something wrong... the question is, can i link a dylib from one pod to another pod? and if so... how?

Comment: In the second podspec: There are missing "=" between `ss.dependency` and the dependencies. A typo after you cleaned it to show us I guess? Also, why do you have two `ss.dependecy` Can't you put it into one line? I'm wondering what happens if you have various lines like this, does it add the or take only the first or the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the disparity between "libs" and "Frameworks", this looks like an issue with either [runpath search paths](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/RunpathDependentLibraries.html) (the running app is not looking for the library from Frameworks), or with the install name of the library not matching the location where it's placed relative to where it is dynamically loaded from.

1. Make sure that in the app that bundles the dynamic library you have the following paths included in your "Runpath Search Path": `@executable_path/../Frameworks`, `@loader_path/../Frameworks`
2. Make sure that the "Dynamic Library Install Name" name of the library being loaded is set to the equivalent of `@rpath/$(EXECUTABLE_PATH)` (i.e. in your case it should be "@rpath/libicudata.57.1.dylib"). You can set it during build time using the `-install_name` compiler (linker?) flag, or with [`install_name_tool`](http://log.zyxar.com/blog/2012/03/10/install-name-on-os-x/), like so: `install_name_tool -id "@rpath/libicudata.57.1.dylib" libicudata.57.1.dylib` . Hopefully doesn't come to this though.

Comment: Meanwhile I was able to solve it... basically the second option that you mentioned was the problem in my case. Even though I was able to answer the question myself some days ago and you being some minutes to late I'll award you the bounty for the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks! This install name stuff is super fiddly always, and Xcode's defaults really don't make it easy to get right for more complex scenarios.